# Text is below the button's canvas kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I've created a rounded button. This is the reference: https://kivycoder.com/rounded-buttons-with-kivy-python-kivy-gui-tutorial-22/

However, the text is below the canvas, which looks like this [result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbRDg.png)

Here is my code:

```
roundbutton = """
<RoundButton@Button>:
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
    background_normal: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.color
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [(20, 20), (20, 20), (20, 20), (20, 20)]
"""

Builder.load_string(roundbutton)

class RoundButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

class ScrButton(RoundButton):
    def __init__(self, screen, direction='right', goal='main', **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = screen
        self.direction = direction
        self.goal = goal

    def on_press(self):
        self.screen.manager.transition.direction = self.direction
        self.screen.manager.current = self.goal

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        layout = FloatLayout()


        login_button = ScrButton(self, direction='left', goal='dashboard', text='[b]LOGIN[/b]', markup=True, color = (237/255, 221/255, 182/255, 1), size_hint=(.8, .07), pos_hint={'center_x':.5, 'center_y':.3})
        layout.add_widget(login_button)
        


        self.add_widget(layout)
```

Here is my expected result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAEPX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `self.color` in your `kv` as the color of your `Button`. However, `color` is already defined as the text color, so you are guaranteeing that text color is the same as your `Button` color as therefor invisible. To see this, try changing that section of your `kv` to:

```
<RoundButton@Button>:
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
    background_normal: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: [1, 0, 0, 1]
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [(20, 20), (20, 20), (20, 20), (20, 20)]
```

The above demonstrates that you cannot use the `color` property as the color of the `Button` since it is already used as the color of the text. To set the color of the `Button` you must create a new property for that. For example, create a new property named `rounded_color`:

```
class ScrButton(RoundButton):
    rounded_color = ListProperty([0, 0, 0, 1])  # new property added
```

Then use that new property in the `kv`:

```
<RoundButton@Button>:
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
    background_normal: ''
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.rounded_color  # do not use the color property here
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [(20, 20), (20, 20), (20, 20), (20, 20)]
```

And finally, set the value of that new property:

```
    # set the rounded_color property here
    login_button = ScrButton(self, direction='left', goal='dashboard', text='[b]LOGIN[/b]', markup=True,
                             rounded_color=(237 / 255, 221 / 255, 182 / 255, 1), size_hint=(.8, .07),
                             pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .3})
```

Comment: What should I do if I want to modify the color of RoundButton?

Comment: See updated answer.